# Why my Authentication State Provider not work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.1

I use blazor with server side render and I want to do my own AuthenticationStateProvider, but it's not work and I do not know why.

My ovveride method in **public class LocalAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider**:

```
    public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        if (await _storageService.ContainKeyAsync("User"))
        {
            var userInfo = await _storageService.GetItemAsync<LocalUserInfo>("User");

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim("Email", userInfo.Email),
                new Claim("FirstName", userInfo.FirstName),
                new Claim("LastName", userInfo.LastName),
                new Claim("AccessToken", userInfo.AccessToken),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userInfo.Id),
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "BearerToken");
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var state = new AuthenticationState(user);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(state));
            return state;
        }

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal());
    }
```

My Login Page:

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider

await storageService.SetItemAsync("User", userInfo);
await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
```

My Startup.cs

```
        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddAuthorizationCore();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, LocalAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

My **Index.razor** for check auth. This always NotAuthorized

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    <h1>Hi! @context.User.FindFirst("FirstName").Value</h1>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <RadzenButton Text="login" Click="GoToRegister"></RadzenButton>
</NotAuthorized>
<Authorizing>
    <h1>Authentication in progress</h1>
    <p>Only visible while authentication is in progress.</p>
</Authorizing>
```

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Login page you should inject `LocalAuthenticationStateProvider`

```
@inject LocalAuthenticationStateProvider LocalAuthStateProvider
```

After doing:

```
await storageService.SetItemAsync("User", userInfo);
```

which I guess, storing the user's information, let subscribers, such as the `CascadingAuthenticationState`, know that the Authentication state has been changed.
This is done so:

```
LocalAuthStateProvider.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged();
```

Your custom AuthenticationStateProvider should be like the following:

```
public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity;

    if (await _storageService.ContainKeyAsync("User"))
    {
        var userInfo = await _storageService.GetItemAsync<LocalUserInfo> 
                                                                ("User");

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim("Email", userInfo.Email),
            new Claim("FirstName", userInfo.FirstName),
            new Claim("LastName", userInfo.LastName),
            new Claim("AccessToken", userInfo.AccessToken),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userInfo.Id),
        };

        identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims );


    }
    else
    {
          identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
    }
    return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new 
                                             ClaimsPrincipal(identity)));

}

public void NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged()
{
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
 }
```

And your Startup class should be like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthorization();
       // services.AddAuthorizationCore();

        services.AddScoped<LocalAuthenticationStateProvider>();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<LocalAuthenticationStateProvider>());

    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi! I just try it and it's not work. So I see this call method GetAuthenticationStateAsync() and by debug I saw this added claims, but <AuthorizeView> still not thinking, that Im authorized. 
Is this problem with App.razor page?

Comment: Sorry, now it's work fine, I don't know whats happen. Thank you